# hybris synchronization - No accessor found for attribute

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

*Hybris version: 5.0.3.7*

I copied data folder from other developer to setup my local hybris environment. When I tried to synchronize the synchronization failed with errors. I'm new to hybris and I have no clue about environment setup errors.

1. No accessor found for attribute 'navigationNodeList' of type 'de.hybris.platform.cms2.jalo.pages.ContentPage'. It seems that this attribute was removed from items.xml. If this was intended please remove the related attribute descriptor manually, for example using the hMC. - **How to do this? I can see this attribute in DEV and QA and I don't find point it should be removed**
2. error copying 8796125987890 due to type class change class de.hybris.platform.cms2.jalo.restrictions.GroupRestriction -> class de.hybris.platform.cms2.jalo.restrictions.UserRestriction is not allowed since types are not compatible - **How to fix this?**

Log:

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:14:59.328 | 2015-09-26 05:14:59 INFO  [00004RHV::de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.CatalogVersionSyncJob] (00004RHV) [CatalogVersionSyncJob] Starting synchronization ...
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.324 | 2015-09-26 05:15:04 ERROR [SyncWorker<00004RHV 1 of 1>] (00004RHV) [accessor] No accessor found for attribute 'navigationNodeList' of type 'de.hybris.platform.cms2.jalo.pages.ContentPage'. It seems that this attribute was removed from items.xml. If this was intended please remove the related attribute descriptor manually, for example using the hMC.
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.369 | 2015-09-26 05:15:04 ERROR [SyncWorker<00004RHV 1 of 1>] (00004RHV) [AbstractItemCopyContext] error copying 8796125987890 due to type class change class de.hybris.platform.cms2.jalo.restrictions.GroupRestriction -> class de.hybris.platform.cms2.jalo.restrictions.UserRestriction is not allowed since types are not compatible 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.433 | 2015-09-26 05:15:04 ERROR [SyncWorker<00004RHV 1 of 1>] (00004RHV) [AbstractItemCopyContext] (Failed) CopyReport src:8796125987890, target:8796125922354
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.455 | 
mode:update
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.460 | 
time: total:0ms, read:0ms, copyAttr:0ms, initial:0ms, refs:0ms 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.471 | 
blacklist: {catalogversion=true, modifiedtime=true}
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.480 | 
whitelist: {comments=true, components=true, pages=true, alldocuments=true, owner=true, users=true, uid=true, catalogversion=true, inverserestrictions=true, assignedcockpititemtemplates=true, name=true}
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.525 | 
excluded attributes 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.529 | 
catalogVersion[?] due to blacklist
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.535 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.536 | 2015-09-26 05:15:04 ERROR [SyncWorker<00004RHV 1 of 1>] (00004RHV) [AbstractItemCopyContext] error copying 8796125824048 due to type class change class de.hybris.platform.cms2.jalo.restrictions.GroupRestriction -> class de.hybris.platform.cms2.jalo.restrictions.UserRestriction is not allowed since types are not compatible 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.590 | 2015-09-26 05:15:04 ERROR [SyncWorker<00004RHV 1 of 1>] (00004RHV) [AbstractItemCopyContext] (Failed) CopyReport src:8796125824048, target:8796126053424
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.611 | 
mode:update
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.613 | 
time: total:0ms, read:42ms, copyAttr:0ms, initial:2ms, refs:0ms 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.621 | 
wrote initial attributes 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.624 | 
approvalStatus[?] value:CmsApprovalStatus.approved(approved(8796111503451)) unchanged 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.635 | 
defaultPage[A?] value:true unchanged 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.640 | 
description[AL] value:{8796125823008->de=null,8796125888544->zh=null,8796093055008->en=null,8796125855776->ja=null} unchanged 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.673 | 
homepage[A?] value:false unchanged 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.680 | 
keywords[AL] value:{8796125823008->de=null,8796125888544->zh=null,8796093055008->en=null,8796125855776->ja=null} unchanged 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.697 | 
label[A] value:FCPAPage unchanged 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.705 | 
masterTemplate[?] value:8796125824052 changed into 8796126053428
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.716 | 
name[A] value:FCPA Page unchanged 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.722 | 
onlyOneRestrictionMustApply[A?] value:true unchanged 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.732 | 
title[AL] value:{8796125823008->de=null,8796125888544->zh=null,8796093055008->en=null,8796125855776->ja=null} unchanged 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.753 | 
uid[A?] value:FCPAPage unchanged 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.759 | 
wrote partOf attributes 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.763 | 
allDocuments[PD] value:() unchanged 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.770 | 
bannerComponets[P] value:() unchanged 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.777 | 
flashComponents[P] value:() unchanged 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.784 | 
linkComponents[P] value:(8796125824060) changed into (8796126479420)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.803 | 
navigationNodeList[P] value:<NULL> unchanged 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.811 | 
navigationNodes[P] value:() unchanged 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.817 | 
previewImage[PD] value:<NULL> unchanged 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.824 | 
restrictions[P] value:(8796125987890), NOT YET TRANSLATED!
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.835 | 
wrote other attributes 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.840 | 
assignedCockpitItemTemplates[] value:(), NOT YET TRANSLATED!
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.847 | 
comments[] value:(), NOT YET TRANSLATED!
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.854 | 
lockedBy[] value:<NULL>, NOT YET TRANSLATED!
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.862 | 
blacklist: {catalogversion=true, modifiedtime=true}
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.876 | 
whitelist: {comments=true, onlyonerestrictionmustapply=true, title=true, homepage=true, bannercomponets=true, previewimage=true, restrictions=true, navigationnodes=true, assignedcockpititemtemplates=true, name=true, defaultpage=true, lockedby=true, alldocuments=true, owner=true, keywords=true, uid=true, mastertemplate=true, catalogversion=true, flashcomponents=true, linkcomponents=true, label=true, approvalstatus=true, navigationnodelist=true, description=true}
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.966 | 
excluded attributes 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.970 | 
catalogVersion[?] due to blacklist
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:04.976 | 
.
.
.
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.018 | 2015-09-26 05:15:33 ERROR [SyncWorker<00004RHV 1 of 1>] (00004RHV) [CatalogVersionSyncMaster] Got error from worker SyncWorker<00004RHV 1 of 1> errorText is: Caught unexpected error type class change class de.hybris.platform.cms2.jalo.restrictions.GroupRestriction -> class de.hybris.platform.cms2.jalo.restrictions.UserRestriction is not allowed since types are not compatible  synchronizing <8796125889584-(8796129624683)->8796126118960 null>
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.081 | de.hybris.platform.jalo.JaloInvalidParameterException: type class change class de.hybris.platform.cms2.jalo.restrictions.GroupRestriction -> class de.hybris.platform.cms2.jalo.restrictions.UserRestriction is not allowed since types are not compatible [HY-0]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.140 | 
at de.hybris.platform.jalo.Item$14.compute(Item.java:1706)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.149 | 
at de.hybris.platform.jalo.Item$CachedSetter.set(Item.java:853)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.156 | 
at de.hybris.platform.jalo.Item$CachedSetter.set(Item.java:816)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.163 | 
at de.hybris.platform.jalo.Item.setComposedType(Item.java:1722)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.171 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.ItemCopyCreator.changeType(ItemCopyCreator.java:396)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.183 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.ItemCopyCreator.copy(ItemCopyCreator.java:216)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.194 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.GenericCatalogCopyContext.copy(GenericCatalogCopyContext.java:2260)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.207 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.CatalogVersionSyncCopyContext.copy(CatalogVersionSyncCopyContext.java:523)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.221 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.GenericCatalogCopyContext.copy(GenericCatalogCopyContext.java:2197)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.236 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.GenericCatalogCopyContext.copyPartOfValues(GenericCatalogCopyContext.java:1863)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.254 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.GenericCatalogCopyContext.translate(GenericCatalogCopyContext.java:410)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.267 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.AttributeCopyCreator.copy(AttributeCopyCreator.java:186)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.278 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.ItemCopyCreator.setReferenceAttributesWaitingOnDelay(ItemCopyCreator.java:514)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.296 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.ItemCopyCreator.setPartOfReferences(ItemCopyCreator.java:493)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.313 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.ItemCopyCreator.copy(ItemCopyCreator.java:238)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.324 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.GenericCatalogCopyContext.copy(GenericCatalogCopyContext.java:2260)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.337 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.CatalogVersionSyncCopyContext.copy(CatalogVersionSyncCopyContext.java:523)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.354 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.GenericCatalogCopyContext.copy(GenericCatalogCopyContext.java:2192)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.369 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.CatalogVersionSyncWorker.copyItem(CatalogVersionSyncWorker.java:186)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.383 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.CatalogVersionSyncWorker.doSynchronization(CatalogVersionSyncWorker.java:154)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.392 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.CatalogVersionSyncWorker.run(CatalogVersionSyncWorker.java:99)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.400 | 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.402 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.CatalogVersionSyncWorkerThread.run(CatalogVersionSyncWorkerThread.java:80)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.411 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.427 | 2015-09-26 05:15:34 ERROR [SyncWorker<00004RHV 1 of 1>] (00004RHV) [AbstractItemCopyContext] error copying 8796125955122 due to type class change class de.hybris.platform.cms2.jalo.restrictions.GroupRestriction -> class de.hybris.platform.cms2.jalo.restrictions.UserRestriction is not allowed since types are not compatible 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.449 | 2015-09-26 05:15:34 ERROR [SyncWorker<00004RHV 1 of 1>] (00004RHV) [AbstractItemCopyContext] (Failed) CopyReport src:8796125955122, target:8796125889586
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.460 | 
mode:update
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.461 | 
time: total:0ms, read:0ms, copyAttr:0ms, initial:0ms, refs:0ms 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.465 | 
blacklist: {catalogversion=true, modifiedtime=true}
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.469 | 
whitelist: {comments=true, components=true, pages=true, alldocuments=true, owner=true, users=true, uid=true, catalogversion=true, inverserestrictions=true, assignedcockpititemtemplates=true, name=true}
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.483 | 
excluded attributes 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.485 | 
catalogVersion[?] due to blacklist
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.487 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.557 | 2015-09-26 05:15:34 ERROR [SyncWorker<00004RHV 1 of 1>] (00004RHV) [CatalogVersionSyncMaster] Got error from worker SyncWorker<00004RHV 1 of 1> errorText is: Caught unexpected error type class change class de.hybris.platform.cms2.jalo.restrictions.GroupRestriction -> class de.hybris.platform.cms2.jalo.restrictions.UserRestriction is not allowed since types are not compatible  synchronizing <8796125955122->8796125889586 null>
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.587 | de.hybris.platform.jalo.JaloInvalidParameterException: type class change class de.hybris.platform.cms2.jalo.restrictions.GroupRestriction -> class de.hybris.platform.cms2.jalo.restrictions.UserRestriction is not allowed since types are not compatible [HY-0]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.602 | 
at de.hybris.platform.jalo.Item$14.compute(Item.java:1706)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.605 | 
at de.hybris.platform.jalo.Item$CachedSetter.set(Item.java:853)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.608 | 
at de.hybris.platform.jalo.Item$CachedSetter.set(Item.java:816)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.611 | 
at de.hybris.platform.jalo.Item.setComposedType(Item.java:1722)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.614 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.ItemCopyCreator.changeType(ItemCopyCreator.java:396)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.620 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.ItemCopyCreator.copy(ItemCopyCreator.java:216)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.628 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.GenericCatalogCopyContext.copy(GenericCatalogCopyContext.java:2260)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.635 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.CatalogVersionSyncCopyContext.copy(CatalogVersionSyncCopyContext.java:523)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.642 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.GenericCatalogCopyContext.copy(GenericCatalogCopyContext.java:2192)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.650 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.CatalogVersionSyncWorker.copyItem(CatalogVersionSyncWorker.java:186)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.659 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.CatalogVersionSyncWorker.doSynchronization(CatalogVersionSyncWorker.java:154)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.668 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.CatalogVersionSyncWorker.run(CatalogVersionSyncWorker.java:99)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.677 | 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.680 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.CatalogVersionSyncWorkerThread.run(CatalogVersionSyncWorkerThread.java:80)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.689 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.689 | 2015-09-26 05:15:35 ERROR [SyncWorker<00004RHV 1 of 1>] (00004RHV) [AbstractItemCopyContext] error copying 8796125987890 due to type class change class de.hybris.platform.cms2.jalo.restrictions.GroupRestriction -> class de.hybris.platform.cms2.jalo.restrictions.UserRestriction is not allowed since types are not compatible 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.711 | 2015-09-26 05:15:35 ERROR [SyncWorker<00004RHV 1 of 1>] (00004RHV) [AbstractItemCopyContext] (Failed) CopyReport src:8796125987890, target:8796125922354
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.721 | 
mode:update
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.722 | 
time: total:0ms, read:0ms, copyAttr:0ms, initial:0ms, refs:0ms 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.726 | 
blacklist: {catalogversion=true, modifiedtime=true}
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.730 | 
whitelist: {comments=true, components=true, pages=true, alldocuments=true, owner=true, users=true, uid=true, catalogversion=true, inverserestrictions=true, assignedcockpititemtemplates=true, name=true}
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.743 | 
excluded attributes 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.745 | 
catalogVersion[?] due to blacklist
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.747 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.747 | 2015-09-26 05:15:35 ERROR [SyncWorker<00004RHV 1 of 1>] (00004RHV) [CatalogVersionSyncMaster] Got error from worker SyncWorker<00004RHV 1 of 1> errorText is: Caught unexpected error type class change class de.hybris.platform.cms2.jalo.restrictions.GroupRestriction -> class de.hybris.platform.cms2.jalo.restrictions.UserRestriction is not allowed since types are not compatible  synchronizing <8796125987890->8796125922354 null>
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.778 | de.hybris.platform.jalo.JaloInvalidParameterException: type class change class de.hybris.platform.cms2.jalo.restrictions.GroupRestriction -> class de.hybris.platform.cms2.jalo.restrictions.UserRestriction is not allowed since types are not compatible [HY-0]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.796 | 
at de.hybris.platform.jalo.Item$14.compute(Item.java:1706)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.801 | 
at de.hybris.platform.jalo.Item$CachedSetter.set(Item.java:853)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.805 | 
at de.hybris.platform.jalo.Item$CachedSetter.set(Item.java:816)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.810 | 
at de.hybris.platform.jalo.Item.setComposedType(Item.java:1722)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.815 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.ItemCopyCreator.changeType(ItemCopyCreator.java:396)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.822 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.ItemCopyCreator.copy(ItemCopyCreator.java:216)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.830 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.GenericCatalogCopyContext.copy(GenericCatalogCopyContext.java:2260)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.839 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.CatalogVersionSyncCopyContext.copy(CatalogVersionSyncCopyContext.java:523)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.848 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.GenericCatalogCopyContext.copy(GenericCatalogCopyContext.java:2192)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.856 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.CatalogVersionSyncWorker.copyItem(CatalogVersionSyncWorker.java:186)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.865 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.CatalogVersionSyncWorker.doSynchronization(CatalogVersionSyncWorker.java:154)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.874 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.CatalogVersionSyncWorker.run(CatalogVersionSyncWorker.java:99)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.882 | 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.885 | 
at de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.CatalogVersionSyncWorkerThread.run(CatalogVersionSyncWorkerThread.java:80)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.903 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.904 | 2015-09-26 05:15:35 INFO  [00004RHV::de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.CatalogVersionSyncJob] (00004RHV) [CatalogVersionSyncMaster] 1. pass, 3 (+3) of 4 items processed (75 %),  0.08 items/sec, 0 (+0) items dumped.
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2015/09/26 05:15:35.942 | 2015-09-26 05:15:35 WARN  [00004RHV::de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.synchronization.CatalogVersionSyncJob] (00004RHV) [CatalogVersionSyncJob] Finished synchronization in 0d 00h:00m:36s:357ms. There were errors during the synchronization!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding (1):

You can go to your hmc (e.g. http://localhost:9001/hmc/hybris?wid=MC0x0) and go to:
System -> Types:

Search for ContentPage.

Open the type (double click)..

Then go to the "Properties" tab and look for the obsolete attribute, double click it and in the newly opened window you can click the "Delete" button in the dark blue header.
That should remove the old attribute descriptor.

Regarding (2):

The (2) problem is difficult to analyze, but it sounds like your hybris version is not the same as the one where you copied the data folder or you might not have copied the database as well?
Ideally, if you try to copy the data folder from a coworker etc, you should at least have the exact same hybris version (and same localextensions.xml, local.properties etc) and also import a dump of that database.

Basically, if you develop using some pre-existing data folder, that one must match the database as well.

Hope that helps (a bit)

Answer (score 0):

1. Ignore.
2. Delete item 8796125922354 and try again.