# Hybris: Error on initiating the workflow on removing print extension - unexpected validator error: cannot find spring bean

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Not sure where to check it. No dependencies are found in xml files. I don't find constraints related to this.

INFO | jvm 1 | main | 2017/03/14 11:10:30.867 | ESC[mESC[0;33m2017-03-14 11:10:30 WARN [Thread-17] [10.0.12.6] [EditorArea] Cound not update item, reason: [com.sbs.ecomm.hybris.sbproductcockpit.workflow.SBProductWor‌​kflowCreationInterce‌​ptor@5d47afd3]: unexpected validator error: cannot find spring bean [workflowAssignedJobAttributeHandler] configured for dynamic attribute [Workflow.assignedJob] from extension [print]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dynamic attribute handler was initially defined in the print extension.
When the system was initialized the type system therefore got the attribute `assignedJob` stored in the database.
Now you removed the extension and the code for this dynamic attribute. That's why you get the error at runtime, because the type system in the database still has this attribute registered and tries to load the value using the dynamic attribute handler (for which the code is no longer present).
You can manually remove the assignedJob attribute through the hmc/backoffice in the type management section as far as I know (for sure thats possible in the hmc).
If an extension has been removed (that has previously been present) the typesystem in the database is not automatically removed.
You might also take a look at the orphaned types in the hac. All types of the print extension should show up there now as they are in the database but no longer present in the code/platform.

(Just remembered that I answered a similar problem for missing attributes here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32824789/932201 .. that contains the steps how to remove an attribute)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sebastian, I have already cleaned up orphaned types in the hac and also verified in hmc (system -> types) that no types related to extension print is present. "You can manually remove the assignedJob attribute through the hmc/backoffice in the type management section" - What is this? How and where in hmc I see attributes?

Comment: see the detailed steps for the hmc in the answer I linked (http://stackoverflow.com/a/32824789/932201). Instead of "ContentPage" you would have to search for the type "Workflow". On the properties tab you should be able to see "assignedJob" as attribute. You shoud be able to delete that which should get rid off the error. Let me know if that works. Cheers

Comment: but: If the SBProductWor‌​kflowCreationInterce‌​ptor uses the assignedJob attribute you will get other runtime errors of course (or won't be able to build your project until those references are removed)   (as alain.janinm stated in his answer)

Comment: I see below error. I don't find this attribute in my custom spring configs. SEVERE: >>de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.exceptions.SystemException: No registered attribute handler for attribute 'assignedJob'. Check your Spring configuration.

Comment: I looked at workflow xml representation on hmc and I notice assignedjob attribute exists. I have ran a plaform update choosing workflow extension.

Comment: hmm.. that's odd. Then something must have gone wrong when you removed the attribute assignedJob in the first place. It shouldn't be showing up in the type afterwards anymore (not listed in the properties tab nor in the xml representation).. hope you get it sorted out!

Answer (score 0):

In your class `SBProductWor‌​kflowCreationInterce‌​ptor` you probably save a `Workflow` model. This model has an handler and both are defined in the print extension.

You can't remove the print extension without removing the dependancies in your custom classes.